# tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0rc1 loss very high - what changed?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I tried today tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0rc1 and I see the loss is very high. The same script running on tensorboard==2.1.0 show good loss. I have only one GPU and no distributed strategy used. What can be wrong with 2.2.0rc1 - except is rc1?

Val Loss 2.1.0:
[Val Loss 2.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkxwz.png)

Val Loss 2.2.0rc1:
[Val Loss 2.2.0rc1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYFBC.png)

Comment: underlying gradients can be different. Try to check that. I have experienced that.

Comment: Still cannot find any reason yet. O'll wait for newer version and check again

Comment: I think if you try these steps you should be able to figure it out 1. The weights of the network initialized in both cases should be the same. 2 check loss value in one forward path. 3 check the gradients are the same in both the cases during one  forward path
You will where the difference is coming from.